# How to display clob column data on page item APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to display the clob column on Page Item. but, it shows the below error message:

I've done the following:

1. Created page item with display only.
2. Add plsql returned function into the page item with the below code:

   ```
   DECLARE
   L_CLOB CLOB;
   begin
   select p_data INTO  l_clob from testdel;
   :P2_NEW := L_CLOB;
   END;
   ```
3. But, it shows as error message.

I would like to return more than 4000 characters. But, no success.

> Error computing item source value for page item P2_NEW.
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong, please try using below instructions.

Data length stored in table : >4000

[image: Data lenght]

- first Create item as display only

[image: Item Property]

- Item Source

[image: Item Source]

- Item Output

[image: Item OUtput]

Please let me know if any issue there . 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ashish. Your solution works, if the clob column is below 4000 characters. But, if it is exceeds 4000 characters then it is throwing the error as "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error".

Comment: No you can see i have attached a screen shot for item output, there are more than 4000 char stored in item.

Which version you are using????
i did on 5.1